Why is choon the phonetic rendering of tune?
I read on https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/choon that the etymology of the word choon is:

Phonetic rendering of tune.

Why is choon the phonetic rendering of tune? Isn't "choo" typically pronounced as "tʃu" (IPA notation) while "tune" is pronounced as "tjuːn" or "tuːn" (US)?

The second syllable of virtue is pronounced the same in BrE and AmE, but as a general rule Americans don't palatalize many of the --tu- words that Brits do palatalize. E.g. Fortuitous, all the -tude words (gratitude, altitude, solitude,  fortitude, etc), and others, though sometimes we do, as in misfortune (yes), opportunity (some speakers do, some don't). It's a mixed bag.

If you look at the definition of the word on that page, it actually begins with (British). This is a phonetic rendering specifically of a British English pronunciation of tune.

Even in British English the correct pronunciation uses the 't' sound, but in casual speech the syllable 'tu' often becomes 'chu' or 'choo'.

@KateBunting - yes. I say it something like 'tyoon'. In older novels writers would use things like 'choon', 'yus', 'loike', etc to condescendingly show regional speech such as Cockney.

Rose Posie - of one British English pronunciation of 'tune'.
